# Masking a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I have a panel in my jsp page.When that panel is clicked I want to mask a div (using Block UI plugin) in the page.
For that I have written the following code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#workflowApprove').click(function() { 
          $('div.hideThis').block({ message: null });
    });
});
```

This works fine when I manually do the clicking.
But when I click the button from back end using java code it does not work.
This is because the clicking occurs before the document is loaded (As it clicked from back end). I could not figure out a way to solve this.

Comment: How can clicking occur before the document is loaded? What is it clicking on?

Comment: if it's happening on backend, there's nothing you can do on the front end because it happens before your javascript gets executed. But, even  then, a click from back end makes 0 sense because on the backend there is nothing to click on.

Comment: Maybe you can try adding something like `$('#workflowApprove').trigger('click')` to your `document.ready` function, so that on load the div clicks itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#workflowApprove').trigger('click')
  });
    $('#workflowApprove').click(function() { 
          $('div.hideThis').block({ message: null });
                });
```